# Notification when server is not running in vaadin

Tags: vaadin

I am having a simple vaadin 7 application with both server and client side components. 
The client side component is making rpc call to server side component through connector.
Now, if I want to track whether the server is alive or not when the call to the server is made, how should that be implemented? I need the notification in the client and after capturing it, some code needs to be executed in client (connector).

Comment: Can't you just write script in js? In example if server didn't respond since certain amount of time (5-10 sec) make alert('sth')

Comment: Vaadin 7.6 itself shows a message when the server does not respond. Maybe this is sufficient for your needs now?